# How to load a spark-nlp pre-trained model from disk

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, apache-spark-mllib, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

From the `spark-nlp` Github [page](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#downloading-models-for-offline-use) I downloaded a `.zip` file containing a pre-trained NerCRFModel. The zip contains three folders: embeddings, fields, and metadata.

How do I load that into a Scala `NerCrfModel` so that I can use it? Do I have to drop it into HDFS or the host where I launch my Spark Shell? How do I reference it?

Answer (score 5):

you just need to provide the path where the folders you mentioned are contained,

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.crf.NerCrfModel
val path = "path/to/unziped/file/folder"
val model = NerCrfModel.read.load(path)
// use your model
model.setInputCols(someCol)
model.transform(yourData) // which contains 'someCol',
```

As long as I remember, you can place the folder in local FS or distributed FS, hope this helps other users as well!.

best,
Alberto.

Comment: For users of Java: You need to cast the result of `load(...)` to the required Class. And somehow I think the SparkNLP API here should be consistent with Spark's `PretrainedPipeline.fromDisk()`.